# Multiple Bootstrap carousels on a page (using ngFor), prev/next buttons not working

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

I am working on a mock eCommerce site, where I have added multiple cards displaying various products from a sample JSON file. I have also added multiple Bootstrap carousels to my page, displaying images of each product.
Here is the code segment:

```
<div class="row row-cols-3 g-4">
  <div *ngFor="let p of product">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <div
          id="{{p.id}}"
          class="carousel slide"
          data-bs-ride="carousel"
        >
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div
              class="carousel-item"
              *ngFor="let i of p.images; let x = index"
              [ngClass]="{ active: x == 0 }"
            >
              <img [src]="i" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
            </div>
          </div>

          <button
            class="carousel-control-prev"
            type="button"
            [attr.data-target]=" '#' + p.id "
            data-bs-slide="prev"
          >
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button
            class="carousel-control-next"
            type="button"
            [attr.data-target]=" '#' + p.id "
            data-bs-slide="next"
          >
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ p.title }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Name : {{ p.title }} <br />
            Description : {{ p.description }} <br />
            Price :{{ p.price }} <br />
            Rating : {{ p.rating }}<br />
            Brand : {{ p.brand }}
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I cannot get the prev/next buttons on any carousel in the website to work.

Here is a sample JSON object that I'm working with :

```
      "id": 1,
      "title": "iPhone 9",
      "description": "An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
      "price": 549,
      "discountPercentage": 12.96,
      "rating": 4.69,
      "stock": 94,
      "brand": "Apple",
      "category": "smartphones",
      "thumbnail": "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
      "images": [
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/1.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/2.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/3.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/4.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg"
      ]
```

I have tried implementing various fixes, such as including property binding in the  tag, but to no avail. I am guessing that my problem lies in the position of the second *ngFor loop which loads the images, but I cannot figure out where else to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector in the way "#1" can cause problems.

Try give an id like `[attr.id]="'p'+p.id"` and `[attr.data-target]="'#p'+p.id"` to give an "id" in the way "p#".

In this way, it's looks like work, see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nprmf3?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)

Comment: That seemed to have fix the problem. Thank you so much!